# Надо, чтобы крутилось одно колесо, а крутятся все картинки на странице

Tags: css

помогите, пожалуйста!
Мне нужно заставить крутиться колесо. Я вставила код CSS. У меня закрутились все картинки на странице))
Я не разбираюсь в этом, но так совпало, что пришлось залезть. Как исправить?
Код вот такой:

```css
img {
   margin-top:20px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotation;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-name: rotation;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
    0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(720deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: добавьте код html. суть в том что у вас в css файле анимация приписывается ВСЕМ тегам IMG. укажите для нужного IMG id или class

Comment: код html вот такой? <img src="ссылка на картинку" /> Если да, то я так вставляю, выдает ошибку. Пробовала вставлять и в окно кода с CSS, и отдельно html, отдельно CSS

Comment: Что за ошибка,?

Comment: восклицательный знак и unexpected token in line и т.д.

Comment: я всё нашла, спасибо))